# FAT date resolution timestamps on Windows

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, resolution, filetime

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table), FAT32 has a date resolution of 2 seconds for last modified time. This file time is obtainable in WinAPI and as a `DateTime` in C# using `File.IO`, both of which this concerns.

What does the date resolution mean in practice? Does it mean that it can only timestamp the last modified file time in 2-second intervals, or does it mean that the dates it timestamped are only accurate within 2 seconds?

In other words (using a `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fffffff` [`DateTime` format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) as examples), does it...

1. Timestamp such that it is limited to 2-second even intervals of time, such as: `2015-07-16 14:28:36:0000000`, `2015-07-16 14:28:38:0000000`, `2015-07-16 14:28:40:0000000`

...or...

2. Arbitrarily timestamp, just that the time is only accurate within a certain interval: `2015-07-16 14:28:36:1234567` - meaning that the last write could have actually taken place anywhere from 2-seconds before this time (`2015-07-16 14:28:34:1234567`) all the way up to 2-seconds after this time (`2015-07-16 14:28:38:1234567`)?
3. Something else?

Comment: Keep in mind also that FAT only records the *local* time.  It is not aware of time zones.  If you take a FAT formatted USB drive from one system to another, there's no guarantee the time zones will match.  Additionally, it cannot disambiguate between times during the fall-back daylight saving time transition (such as when 01:00-01:59 is repeated in the US).  NTFS records the UTC time, so it does not have this problem.

Comment: @MattJohnson Interesting, thanks for noting that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the number of seconds in the time can only be an even integral number.

The [directory entry for the FAT file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#Directory_entry) only has a 5-bit field for storing the number of seconds in the time. This limits the number stored in the field to the range 0-31, which is multiplied by two to obtain the number of seconds. (Values of 30 and 31 in this field are invalid.)

Comment: Thanks so much. Awesome reference. Indeed, at offset 0x0E it shows that this value contains Seconds/2 (where Seconds can be from 0-29) within bits 4-0. Of these numbers (0-29), multiplying any of them by 2 to get the actual seconds produces a number that is limited to 2-second even intervals of time.